# How bad is it to momentarily overload a transformer?

Tags: transformer, ac, load, step-down

I have an espresso machine from the US running on a transformer in the UK.  Inside the machine there is a grinder, a pump, and some heating elements.  The machine is labeled 120VAC 1150W.

[image]

I have it connected to a hefty 1000W wound transformer (this is not a travel transformer!).  It seems to work fine.  Here is the label from the transformer:

[image]

I've connected up an ammeter to the mains side and when both heating elements kick in, it momentarily draws 1050W.  If I run the grinder at the same time, it draws 1220W total.  Running the pump, grinder, and all the heating elements draws up to just under 1250W.  The heating elements are only one for a minute or two and then it drops down to about 50W.  Even when you are trying to shoot continuous shots of espresso, the machine is not heating all the time.

The transformer gets warm as they normally do but definitely not hot, certainly not too hot to hold or touch.  The transformer's 6A fuse never blows which makes sense because that's 1500W at 6A.

My question is, if this transformer is rated at 1000W, generally how bad is it to momentarily go over this rating?  I'm guessing there is always some leeway in the ratings and that it's probably rated at 1000W for continuous use so my momentary 1250W draws are probably fine and given it's fused even at 6A.  It all seems fine, should I be worried?

Comment: Its rating may be conservative, and it must meet that rating at some high ambient temperature and 100% duty cycle. Unless your kitchen is that warm or your name is Starbuck you'll probably be fine.

Comment: On the other hand, the rating **might not** be that conservative. You said "momentarily" but then you talk about exceeding the limit for "a minute or two". The bottom line is that you are violating the specified power limits for the device. If it causes a fire you may end up having a difficult conversation with your insurance company.

Comment: By momentary, I do mean a minute or two.  The fact that it's fused at 6A tells me it probably is conservative.

Comment: To me, a "moment" is much, much shorter than a "minute". It's important to use clear and precise language in engineering. And yes, it "probably" won't start a fire. And you "probably" won't get COVID. And you "probably" won't get hit by a car if you close your eyes and cross the street. And you "probably" won't get sick if you eat sushi that was left out overnight. So go ahead!

Comment: Momentarily overloading a transformer even for a few minutes, perhaps 15 to 30 minutes is no big deal. Transformers have a lot of mass in their copper and iron. Until the temperature gets high enough to damage the winding insulation, they are fine. However you don't have a transformer, you have an AC/AC converter. That is an electronic product. It is much less forgiving than a transformer. It is difficult to estimate how much abuse they can stand. You need to depend on the manufacturer's literature. The label says "1000 Watts Max." Perhaps the really mean that. The fuse will prevent a fire.

Comment: very short answer: overloaded transformer = voltage spikes.

Answer (score 3):

A transformer should not be overloaded for voltage, at all, for any time at all, at all.

A transformer can be overloaded for current, as long as the temperature of the windings stays within the limits of their insulation.

How long you can overload it depends on the thermal time constant. A 1 kW transformer is a pretty large beast, and I would guess that the relatively small overload you're subjecting it to could be tolerated for many 10s of minutes.

If you want to see what temperature the windings are getting to, and have a DMM, then you can make use of copper's (well, pretty much all elemental metals) temperature coefficient of resistance of 0.4% per °C. Unfortunately, you don't know what the insulation rating of the transformer is, so this exercise could well be moot.

Measure the resistance of the mains winding at ambient. Run it for an hour or three at 1 kW to reach thermal equilibrium, and remeasure the mains winding resistance. Estimate the temperature rise using the 0.4% temperature coefficient. This rise is what the transformer has been rated for.

Now run the transformer at 1250 W, measuring the resistance/temperature every 5 or 10 minutes. Stop the experiment when the temperature rise threatens to exceed the rated rise. Now you know how long you can over-run it without exceeding its rated temperature rise.

Comment: I would agree if this was a simple transformer. But the label says it's a "Step Down Converter". I.e. you have to check for the junction temperature of some of the electronics as well.

Comment: I wasn't aware a step down converter could not just be a transformer transformer.  I don't think there's any circuit board in this thing.

Comment: I would not consider "AC/AC converter" printed on the label to be appropriate for a transformer, but I now that I have looked closely at the picture, I agree that certainly looks like a transformer.